# Brush feathered on one side and sharp on other side

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, brush

Is it possible to create resizable-rotatable brush in photosphop and/or gimp, that is sharp on one side and feathered on other side (and brush can be rotated to when required)?

Comment: Yes. Custom brushes can be made in both Photoshop and GIMP. A custom brush can be anything you want. Both applications have ways to rotate a brush.

Answer (score 1):

### For Gimp:

Technically, yes:

[image: brush]

But it's quite hard to control the actual opacity gradient, since the overlap between successive copies of the brush depend on the curve radius:

[image]

Maybe your problem has a [solution](http://gimp-wrapmap.sourceforge.net/) which doesn't involve such a brush?

Answer (score 1):

For Photoshop, pretty much any image can be converted to a brush. And all brushes can be rotated around their center axis.